# Instead of its id, I want to display Django values() on Foreign Key in template as object

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, foreign-keys

I'm having some trouble to show a value on a foreign key in Django instead of its id, so can any of you help me?

my models:

I have a DONOR

```
class Donor(models.Model):
    donor_first_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    donor_middle_name=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    donor_last_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I have a Horse that have a donor:

```
lass Horse(models.Model):
    horse_donor=models.ForeignKey(Donor)
```

and my views:

```
def horse_form(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form =HorseForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponse('<script language="JavaScript"> alert("You have sucessful created a new Volunteer"); location.href="/login/horse/" </script>')
else:
    form = HorseForm()

return render(request, 'loginPortal/horse_form.html', {'form' : form })
```

my form:

```
class HorseForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
        model = Horse
```

I want to be able to show the donor name on the horse form so it cam be related to horse donor. However, my form just show a "donor object" on the form. Can any help me with this? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `__str__` method like this:

```
class Donor(models.Model):
    donor_first_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    donor_middle_name=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    donor_last_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s %s" % (self.donor_first_name, self.donor_middle_name, self.donor_last_name)
```

Another approach is to use custom subclass of ModelChoiceField

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Donor, Horse

class MyModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "%s %s %s" % (self.donor_first_name, self.donor_middle_name, self.donor_last_name)

class HorseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    horse_donor = forms.MyModelChoiceField(queryset=Donor.objects.all())
    # other fields (if any), class Meta, etc.
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm newbie in Django so I'm getting some trouble to do my project. That's was exactly what I need.